# Using Yolox on an asset image doesn't draw any detection

Tags: python, object-detection, training-data, yolo, yolov5

So I'm trying to learn how to use Yolox for my bachelor thesis, and after hours of installing and updating components, finally managed to run Yolox on a test image in the assets folder. However, when I go to the output folder, it's the same image there, with no boxes on detected objects and I can't understand why.. Here is the console output:

```
G:\TPD_v2\YOLOX>python tools/demo.py image -n yolox-s -c models/yolox_s.pth --path assets/dog.jpg --conf 0.25 --nms 0.45 --tsize 640 --save_result --device [cpu/gpu]
2022-01-24 11:59:07.079 | INFO     | __main__:main:240 - Args: Namespace(camid=0, ckpt='models/yolox_s.pth', conf=0.25, demo='image', device='[cpu/gpu]', exp_file=None, experiment_name='yolox_s', fp16=False, fuse=False, name='yolox-s', nms=0.45, path='assets/dog.jpg', save_result=True, trt=False, tsize=640)
2022-01-24 11:59:07.202 | INFO     | __main__:main:250 - Model Summary: Params: 8.97M, Gflops: 26.81
2022-01-24 11:59:07.204 | INFO     | __main__:main:261 - loading checkpoint
2022-01-24 11:59:07.280 | INFO     | __main__:main:265 - loaded checkpoint done.
2022-01-24 11:59:07.886 | INFO     | __main__:inference:151 - Infer time: 0.5256s
2022-01-24 11:59:07.887 | INFO     | __main__:image_demo:188 - Saving detection result in ./YOLOX_outputs\yolox_s\vis_res\2022_01_24_11_59_07\dog.jpg
```

Also I'm trying to understand how to use cocodataset to train a model and use it in Yolox, if you know any guides/tutorials that can help me, I'll appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MODEL_PATH = "/best_ckpt.pth.tar"
TEST_IMAGE_PATH = "assets/dog.jpg"

!python /content/YOLOX/tools/demo.py image -f /content/YOLOX/exps/example/yolox_voc/yolox_voc_s.py -c {MODEL_PATH} --path {TEST_IMAGE_PATH} --conf 0.25 --nms 0.45 --tsize 640 --save_result --device cpu
```

You pointed to the downloaded weights instead of the trained weights